# How to evaluate the time spent on digital signing using Omnet++ and Crypto++?

Tags: c++, time, omnet++, crypto++

I am doing a simulation in Omnet++ using the Crypto++ encryption library. I made an adaptation of Tic-Toc13 to send a message and digitally sign it (with the Crypto++ library). My interest is to evaluate the time it would take to complete this whole procedure, but the simulator does not take into account the processing time and the digital signature of the message. What do I need to do to make Omnet++ take this time into consideration? Thanks.

Code to sign the message:

```
  string message("MESSAGE TO SIGN");
  //sign the message
  auto signature(RsaSignString(keys.privateKey, message));

  msg->setMessage0(message.c_str());
  msg->setSign0(signature.c_str());
```

Code to verify the message sign:

```
    if (RsaVerifyString(keys.publicKey, ttmsg->getMessage0(), ttmsg->getSign0())) {
      cout << "Signatue OK!" << endl;
    } else {
      cout << "Signatue NOT OK!" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: dnat, can you provide some of your code and examples of what you've tried so far to get this working?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question with the code.

Comment: It seems like [ed25519](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Ed25519) would be a better choice than RSA nowadays. Especially if you are concerned about performance. Ed25518 is about 20x to 30x faster than equivalent NIST curves. I did not benchmark against 3072-bit RSA, but I am guessing RSA is another 10x slower.

Comment: Also, most Omnet++ questions I come across go unanswered. I see them on occassion when they intersect Crypto++. I don't believe the Omnet++ folks patrol Stack Overflow. The [Omnet++ Mailing Lists](https://omnetpp.org/mailing-list.html) may be helpful to you.

Comment: Ok guys. Thanks. I'll keep looking ...